# CSS headache can't get certain buttons to change background on hover

Tags: css, button, hover

I work with bootstrap a lot and sometimes it's really hard to figure out why certain things don't work when you want to override certain CSS decisions bootstrap makes for you.

So i've been trying to change the background color on a button on hover so that each button gets a different color on mouse hover. But somehow my css class doesn't override it.

Here is what I have so far:

```html
<style type="text/css">
.fblue_background>li>a:hover, .fblue_background>li>a:focus  {
background-color: blue !important;
}
.tblue_background>li>a:hover, .fblue_background>li>a:focus  {
background-color: blue !important;
}
.pred_background>li>a:hover, .fblue_background>li>a:focus  {
background-color: red !important;
}
</style>



<li><a class="fblue_background" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/url"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
<li><a class="tblue_background" target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/url"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
<li><a class="pred_background" target="_blank" href="https://www.pinterest.com/url"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p"></i></a></li>
```

PS: it also doesn't work when I put the class value between `<li>`

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to be complete which makes it difficult to say exactly what the issue is (for example, bootstrap hasn't been included in the snippet). Please modify the snippet to reproduce the issue. Looking at what you have though your CSS selectors will not match the HTML you have. You should try something like `li > a.fblue_background:hover`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're delcaring `.fblue_background` as if it's the parent of the `li`, this isn't the case. See revised code below:

```html
<style type="text/css">
li>a.fblue_background:hover, li>a.fblue_background:focus  {
background-color: blue !important;
}
li>a.tblue_background:hover, li>a.tblue_background:focus  {
background-color: blue !important;
}
li>a.pred_background:hover, li>a.pred_background:focus  {
background-color: red !important;
}
</style>



<li><a class="fblue_background" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/url"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>Hello</a></li>
<li><a class="tblue_background" target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/url"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>Bonjour</a></li>
<li><a class="pred_background" target="_blank" href="https://www.pinterest.com/url"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p"></i>Hi</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.nav>li>.blue:hover, .nav>li>.red:focus  {
  background-color: blue !important;
}
.nav>li>.green:hover, .nav>li>.blue:focus  {
  background-color: #5EACC5 !important;
}
.nav>li>.red:hover, .nav>li>.red:focus  {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply but i've also tried that before, didn't work either.

Comment: oschfotografie.nl/home (trying everything as we speak) xD been on this for the past hour and it's driving me nuts.

Comment: done that, check live version, doesn't work. this is why ive been stuck for more than an hour now. so frustrating

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the `>` method in CSS it would strictly follow the HTML markup. So when you want to change the `a` element, you should be doing

```
a.blue{
background:#0000ff; 
}
```

Comment: Well if I do it without :hover at the end it works but changing the background when nothing is happening was no problem. On hover it doesn't do a thing. Also thanks for the quick reply

Comment: Could you comment below your problem with hover?

Comment: if you don't mind checking out the live version? oschfotografie.nl/home, trying to change the facebook button to facebook-blue on hover

Comment: sorry I have been gone for some time, and yes David Wilkinson fixed it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

To change background of `<a>` link you just need to add :hover for class directly like this.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .fblue_background:hover, .fblue_background:focus  {
        background-color: blue;
    }
    .tblue_background:hover, .fblue_background:focus  {
        background-color: blue;
    }
    .pred_background:hover, .fblue_background:focus  {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>

<ul>
    <li><a class="fblue_background" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/url"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>Facebook</a></li>
    <li><a class="tblue_background" target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/url"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>Twitter</a></li>
    <li><a class="pred_background" target="_blank" href="https://www.pinterest.com/url"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p"></i>Pinterest</a></li>
</ul>
```

jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/g9y2v91e/